# Mongo Exception doesn't raise

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB driver 2.7.3

I've been looking for some information about MongoExceptions

Here's my code

```
public IList<Evaluation> GetEvaluations()
        {
            try
            {
                return MongoDao.Evaluations.Find<Evaluation>(_ => true).ToList();
            }
            catch (MongoServerException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw new InternalErrorDaoException("There is a problem with the mongo server");
            }
        }
```

But When the server is down It doesn't raise the exception.

Some help please.

Comment: It doesn't raise the exception? What does it do? Give you back invalid data? Or does it throw some other exception?

Comment: Raise this message 
"Unexpected error A timeout occured after 30000ms"

Comment: I debugged it and It doesn't catch the exception

Comment: What happens when you catch Exception rather than a specific MongoServerException? It may be throwing a different exception than you’re expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

If the Error message is "Unexpected error A timeout occured after 30000ms" then you should also catch `System.TimeoutException`. MongoDB driver uses it when the connection timeouts.

```
public IList<Evaluation> GetEvaluations()
{
    try
    {
        return MongoDao.Evaluations.Find<Evaluation>(_ => true).ToList();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw new InternalErrorDaoException("Timeout while trying to connect the mongo server");
    }
    catch (MongoServerException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw new InternalErrorDaoException("There is a problem with the mongo server");
    }
}
```

If you want to use the same logic for both exceptions:

```
public IList<Evaluation> GetEvaluations()
{
    try
    {
        return MongoDao.Evaluations.Find<Evaluation>(_ => true).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (e is TimeoutException || e is MongoServerException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw new InternalErrorDaoException("There is a problem with the mongo server");
    }
}
```